# Pop Back to Native iOS App from FlutterViewController

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I added flutter module into my existing iOS app. Currently for testing I am showing a `FlutterViewController` with ahead of time created `FlutterEngine` in `AppDelegate`. Though the flutter screen comes up correctly I am not able to come back to the native iOS app.

Little googling showed that `SystemNavigator.pop()` will do the work but it is not working for me as it is mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13828) and [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/ios-devs#how-do-i-pop-back-to-the-ios-native-viewcontroller). How can I go back to my native iOS app ?

My swift side code to show the flutter screen looks like this

```swift
@objc func showFlutter() {
      let flutterEngine = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).flutterEngine
      let flutterViewController =
          FlutterViewController(engine: flutterEngine, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        flutterViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
      present(flutterViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

My Flutter side code to pop back to the native iOS app looks like this which is not working.

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
        leading: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
          onPressed: () => SystemNavigator.pop(),
        ),
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
```

If I replace `SystemNavigator.pop()` with `Navigator.of(context).pop()` it does not work either and **shows a black screen** which makes sense as it does not have any fallback route. This is not popping out Screen as much as I understand, it is closing the whole flutter app. Is not it? How can I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

try `exit(0)` when platform is iOS , somehow `SystemNavigator.pop()` does not work.
whole code as below:

```
onPressed: () {
  if(Platform.isIOS) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    exit(0);
  } else {
    SystemNavigator.pop(animated: true);
  }
},
```

Comment: exit close whole app